# How to access the username out of a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup, angular-material

I have a list of users generated with ng-repeat and data from db, which works fine. Now when you click on a user, you get a popup box. I would like to display the name of the selected user in this popup box, but I don't know how to access the username because the ng-repeat does not take place in the popup box.

Note that I work with angular material

Part of my html code:

```
<!-- START SIDEBAR -->
    <div id="logo-wrap">
      <img id="logo" src="assets/images/logo2.png" alt="Zazzle Logo" >
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar" class="md-whiteframe-z4" ng-data-color="">
      <div style="height: 80px;"></div>
      <div class="userList" id="usrL">
        <li id="customLI" ng-repeat="user in users" id="userPos" class="active circular md-whiteframe-z2" style="background-color: {{ user.color }} " ng-click="showPopUpDeletionConfirmation($event, user._id); " ng-data-id="{{ user._id }}">
          <div ng-if="user._id==activeUser" class="wrapperImageCurrentUser" id="marker_active_user"> </div>
          <p class="initials" id="userValue" style="top: {{ user.top }};" >
            <custom id="user._id"></custom>
            {{user.initials}}
            <!-- {{user.email}} -->
          </p>
          <md-tooltip>{{user.name}}</md-tooltip>
        </li>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
```

The code for the popup box (html) resides in the file dialog1.tmpl. This file is just the layout of the popup box nothing relevant to share the code in this question

Here is a visual of my user list and popup box -> https://gyazo.com/694f65c5269cbca910ec6989ee5a77c2

Comment: I didn't understand how you open the popup and if it use the same controller or another one, BTW you can pass the selected user when someone click the circle.

Comment: @Michelem, i didn't add the button for open the popup in the code but what i understand is that i pass the username and id in the ng-click of the button that opens the popup, correct?

Comment: Yes, but showing us the rest of the code should be useful

Answer (score 3):

You don't access the user in the popup, you pass the user to the popup.

You are already sending the users id, just send the entire user. Use `user.name` and `user._id` after you've send it.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
ng-click="showPopUpDeletionConfirmation($event, user._id);"
```

to this:

```
ng-click="showPopUpDeletionConfirmation($event, user);"
```

and access `user` object in the popup

EDIT:

You need also to change the `showPopUpDeletionConfirmation` with this:

```
$scope.showPopUpDeletionConfirmation = function (ev, user) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: 'DialogDeleteUserController',
            templateUrl: 'confirmDeletion.tmpl.html',
            //parent: angular.element(document.body),
            locals: {
                userId: user._id,
                selectedUser: user.name,
            },
            targetEvent: ev,
            hasBackdrop: false,
        })
            .then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                $scope.users = _.filter($scope.users, function (user) {
                    return user._id !== userId;
                })
            }
        });
     }
```

And then you can access the entire `user` object in the popup template with `$scope.selectedUser` or something like `{{selectedUser.name}}`

Comment: do i access it like this:   <h1 class="customH1"> {{ user.name }} </h1>

Comment: Yes, you can pass the entire `user` object to the click event to open the popup, then you can use all its properties like `user.name`

Comment: mmmm it does not seem to work. i pass the entire user object and then called it like so:   <h1 class="customH1"> {{ user.name }} </h1> in the popup box, but nothing

Comment: I need to see the rest of the code, please make a simple JSFiddle you can start from this: http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/79mtkp97/

Comment: here is the plunker -> http://plnkr.co/edit/d4hoguJcxr0zoIDFA97t?p=preview (although the users don't show ...)

Comment: @Michelem, mmm it does not seems to work. this is what i have -> https://gyazo.com/ea6767018f622df0be7e41d6eaed7c20. I have have to leave the userId as a parameter int eh showPopUpDeletionConfirmation because i need it to delete a user

Comment: You can always access the ID with `user.id` its a property of the `user` object like the name

Comment: @Michelem, ok but i don't think the issue is with the locals: { userId: userId}. I believe it does not mater that i declare more then one. It still does not explain why I can't display the user name

Comment: In the image you posted you have `$scope.showPopupDeleteConfirmation(ev, userId, user) {...}` yet in your html you are only passing the user: `showPopupDeleteConfirmation($event, user)`  In doing this, the userId variable you are using in your popup settings is actually the user object. so you what you want in the controller is : `$scope.showPopupDeleteConfirmation(ev, user)` and in the `mdDialog.show` you want `userId: user._id, selectedUser: user.name`

Comment: I've editing @Michelem 's answer to hopefully what you would want in the locals section. I highly recommend reading about [Javascript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)