# How to access data without an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I have a list of user and when you click on a user, a popup box opens up. In that popup box I want to display the selected users name. So via previous post -> [How to access the username out of a ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045411/how-to-access-the-username-out-of-a-ng-repeat) . I was able to log the selected users name in my console but it won't show in the view

This is my code -> https://gyazo.com/85d9675aff33b40995a3fc67ce97e0da

Part of the html:

```
<!-- START SIDEBAR -->
<div id="logo-wrap">
  <img id="logo" src="assets/images/logo2.png" alt="Zazzle Logo" >
</div>
<div id="sidebar" class="md-whiteframe-z4" ng-data-color="">
  <div style="height: 80px;"></div>
  <div class="userList" id="usrL">
    <li id="customLI" ng-repeat="user in users" id="userPos" class="active circular md-whiteframe-z2 disableDoubleClick" style="background-color: {{ user.color }} " ng-click="showPopUpDeletionConfirmation($event, user._id, user.name);"  ng-data-id="{{ user._id }}">
      <div ng-if="user._id==activeUser" class="wrapperImageCurrentUser" id="marker_active_user"> </div>
      <p class="initials" id="userValue" style="top: {{ user.top }};" >
        <custom id="user._id"></custom>
        {{user.initials}}
        <!-- {{user.email}} -->
      </p>
      <md-tooltip>{{user.name}}</md-tooltip>
    </li>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- END SIDEBAR -->
```

The popup box is an md-dialog box (angular material). In the confirmDeletion.tmpl.html file I want to display the selected user name.

```
<h1 class="customH1"> {{ user.name }} </h1>
```

Part of my code for the app.js file

```
    $scope.showPopUpDeletionConfirmation = function(ev, userId, name) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: 'DialogDeleteUserController',
            templateUrl: 'app/calendar/month/confirmDeletion.tmpl.html',
            //parent: angular.element(document.body),
            locals: {
                userId: userId,
                name: name,
            },
            targetEvent: ev,
            hasBackdrop: false,
        })
        .then(function(result){
            if(result) {
                $scope.users = _.filter($scope.users, function(user) {
                    return user._id !== userId;
                })
            }
        });
                  console.log('!!!!!!!!' , name);
    }
```

As you can see from the image -> https://gyazo.com/853685162f2aa9e6fed1d2883b54f28f (selected the last user in the list)

I am logging the selected name but its just not showing

I guess that I am not binding the data correctly with the view ...

Comment: You can get the name from locals: {
                userId: userId,
                name: name,
            }

Comment: When you click on user then pass user object to function which is called on click. Then pass this user object to locals. now you can get the user name from user object like user.name. Can you show me exact code. So i can help you on this.

Comment: @mohansingh: the code is above in my question, btw i did pass the user object on my button => ng-click="showPopUpDeletionConfirmation($event, user._id, user.name);"

Comment: <h1 class="customH1"> {{ user.name }} </h1> this is wrong . {{user.name}} should be {{name}} only.

Comment: @MohanSingh: ok so i changed it just to {{ name }} but still nothing .. This is what i have got now -> https://gyazo.com/946706a8cb1c8e0cc3933fe50e7252c9

Comment: Can you add the console.log(name) in delete function and see if its not null

Comment: output in console still shows the selected user -> https://gyazo.com/875f7075c340beadfcf2e80e2e0d4db9

Comment: Have you injected name in DialogDeleteUserController this controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.controller('DialogDeleteUserController', ['$scope','name','userId' function ($scope, name, userId) {
    $scope.name = name;
    $scope.userId= userId;
}])
```

Comment: yes i added name to the delete controller and when i log it the name comes through. never mind. its working now. thanks